# Overload Resolution with Template Constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
struct X
{
    X(X&);         // (1)
    X(X&&);        // (2)
    X(const X&);   // (3)
    X(const X&&);  // (4)
};
```

Consider the set **U** of all possible usages of `X` where one of these four constructors will be bound and dispatched.

For example one element of **U** is:

```
int main()
{
    X x1 = ...;
    X x2(x1);  // <-- (1) used
}
```

Now imagine we add a fifth constructor as follows:

```
struct X
{
    X(X&);                    // (1)
    X(X&&);                   // (2)
    X(const X&);              // (3)
    X(const X&&);             // (4)

    template<class T> X(T&&); // (5)
};
```

Are there any new overload resolutions where one of the elements of **U** will now dispatch to `(5)` as a better match instead of `(1)`,`(2)`,`(3)` or `(4)` as it previously did?

Comment: Here is the final class relating to this question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20058/a-c11-any-class

Answer (score 4):

Consider derived classes:

```
struct Y : X
{ Y() { } };

int main()
{
  Y y;
  X x1(y); // derived class
}
```

Comment: Also `struct Y1 {operator X(){return {};}};`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I get it now. I guess, the case would be for any T convertible to X. For instance:

```
struct R
{
 operator X() const;
};

int main()
{
  R r{};
  X x{r};
}
```

If your goal is to have one template constructor that handles only your (1) to (4) but nothing else you have to "SFINAE away" the others by something like:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool IsSame() {
  return is_same<
    typename decay<T>::type, 
    typename decay<U>::type
  >::value;
}

struct X
{
  template <class T, typename enable_if<IsSame<T, X>()>::type* = 0> 
  X(T&&);
};
```

Alternatively, if your goal is to tell apart T's convertible to X from the other T's, consider the following solution:

```
struct X
{
  template <
    class T, 
    typename enable_if<is_convertible<T, X>::value>::type* = 0
  > 
  X(T&&); // do something

  template <
    class T, 
    typename enable_if<!is_convertible<T, X>::value>::type* = 0
  > 
  X(T&&); // do something else
};
```

Comment: I think you mean "does not handle (1) to (4) but everything else".

Comment: Basically I want to always give `(1)` to `(4)` priority over `(5)` for every element of __U__.  Will this SFINAE solution work in cases of convertibility (eg derived classes and `operator X` user-defined conversion functions).

Comment: Your original 5-constructor example in the question already gives the priority to non-template constructors over those generated from the template. My proposal behaves like your 4-constructor example.

Comment: Not in the case of `struct Y : X` or `struct R { operator X() }` though.  I would like `(1) to (4)` to retain priority for all elements of __U__ over `(5)`

Comment: That is, the "SFINAE" version will generate only the four constructors (volatile versions aside). These conctructors will force a conversion to X if they are invoked with other types (say, R) convertible to X.

Comment: What do you mean by "priority" or "retain priority" then? Do you want them to still be generated but be a "worse match" when picking the right overload? Are you trying to solve some concrete problem? Can we see it?

Comment: Here is the final class relating to this question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20058/a-c11-any-class

Comment: @Andrew: I updated the reply. Perhaps it helps; if I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: @AndrewTomazosFathomlingCorps: You can use `disable_if<is_convertable<T, X>::value>` to disable the templated constructor for types convertible to X (where both template and non-template could match, but template provides a better match).

Answer (score -1):

```
int main()
{
    X x2(12);  // <-- (5) used
}
```

(T is deduced to be int)

Comment: But this was not valid before the introduction of the templated constructor.

Comment: This usage is not in __U__